# Spreading a number over columns using geometrical distribution in Excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to spread a number over a number of varying columns using a geometrical distribution.

E.g. I have 100 USD that need to be allocated over 10 weeks. Using a geometrical distribution, the highest amount would be allocated in week 1, a lower amount in week 2, ... and the lowest in week 10, with the sum over all weeks making up 100 USD again.

I have several values to distribute, and the # of columns varies, so I'd like to be able to use a standardized geometrical distribution pattern.

Who can help with an appropriate function on the above example?

Thanks
N

Comment: What have you done so far? :)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the fact, that you have not tried anything in the last 5 days, here is what I have came up with:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GeometricCraziness(rngRange As Range, Optional lngAccuracy As Long = 16)

    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim rngLast         As Range

    Dim dblTotal        As Double
    Dim dblLeft         As Double
    Dim dblSumArray     As Double

    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim varArray        As Variant

    dblTotal = rngRange(1, 1)
    dblLeft = dblTotal
    lngCounter = 0

    ReDim varArray(rngRange.Count - 1)

    For Each rngCell In rngRange
        If lngCounter Then
            varArray(lngCounter) = 1 / (2 ^ lngCounter)
            rngCell = Round(dblTotal / (2 ^ lngCounter), lngAccuracy)
            dblLeft = dblLeft - rngCell.value
            Set rngLast = rngCell
        End If
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Next rngCell

    For lngCounter = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
        dblSumArray = dblSumArray + varArray(lngCounter)
    Next lngCounter

    For lngCounter = 1 To UBound(varArray)
        varArray(lngCounter) = Round(varArray(lngCounter) / dblSumArray, lngAccuracy)
    Next lngCounter

    lngCounter = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngRange
        If lngCounter Then
            rngCell = Round(rngCell + rngLast * varArray(lngCounter), lngAccuracy)
        End If
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

You call this `call GeometricCraziness(selection)`
And if you have `555` in the first cell of the selection, you get something like this:
[image]

Its not the best option, but is the best I could think of so far. And it works! :)

The logic is in the following - each next number is at least 50% less than the previous for the first loop with the following formula:

```
?1/2^n

n= 1
1/2^n = 0,5 

n= 2
1/2^n = 0,25

n= 3
1/2^n = 0,125
```

Then, we redistribute the rest in the second loop, using the same formula. With good accuracy (like 16), we get decent values.